# Oracle paging in Entity Framework returning different sets of records than intentionally

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, c#-4.0, pagination

I thought I understood LINQ or did I, or it could be a nasty Oracle provider bug?

Got a very frustrating situation where I want to implement paging in a knockout app.  Using Troy Goode's PagedList Mvc library, I can see where the code was transformed from a search returning two items into a 15 items result (I had set paging to be 15 items per).  Worked perfectly fine in SQL Server 2005/2008, but not so using Oracle.DataAccess.dll v11.2.3/v4.112.3 (depending how the version number gets read).

I did the search result in Linq like thus:

```
var entities = _context.Entities;

var q = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)
                        ? entities
                            .Where(a => a.PRODUCT_NUM.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper())
                                     || a.PRINT_NAME.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper()))
                        : entities;   

var result = q.OrderBy(e => e.UPDATE_DATE == null)
                             .ThenByDescending(e => e.UPDATE_DATE)
                             .Select(r => new EntityModel
                             {
                                 Id = r.ID,
                                 Num = r.PRODUCT_NUM,
                                 Name = r.PRINT_NAME,
                                 City = r.City.PRINT_NAME,
                                 State = r.City.State.PRINT_NAME,
                                 EntityType = r.ENTITY_TYPE,
                                 CompanyType = r.COMPANY_TYPE,
                                 UpdateDate = r.UPDATE_DATE
                             })
                             .ToPagedList(pageNumber, 15);
```

Now at this point, using the Immediate Window, I can have it return 2 items, however when it goes through the paging process, it comes back with 15 items.

First thought, am I having an caching problem or something?  But delved into the PagedList library. https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Let's look at the object passed thru to the PagedList and I'll show you the number of records returned. Inside the PagedList, the IQueryable object is called superset and returns a List eventually, but check out what I'm getting when I query the list via Immediate Window.  I just figured it'd be the best way to show you...

```
?superset.Take(pageSize).Count()
2
?superset.Count()
51114
?superset.Skip(0).Take(pageSize).Count()
2
?superset.ToList().Count()
2
?superset.Skip(0).Take(pageSize).ToList().Count()
15
?superset.Take(pageSize).ToList().Count()
15
```

What's most interesting to me is that when we do a ToList(), it returns 15 records.  Is it an Oracle ODP.NET provider problem?  I fired up Ayende's Entity Framework Provider [efprof.com](http://efprof.com/) and saw the Oracle query being generated, copy-pasted it to TOAD, and it indeeds returns 2 items and not 15.

I'm definitely missing something.

Thanks,
-rob